# Sorting primeng columns

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am using a primeng table and was using their toggle method for the columns. The only issue is, with the columns when you toggle one off and back on it returns the column to the end of the table. I was wondering if anyone knew anyway to sort them so the column goes back to the original position

I tried to use various sorting methods in my component.ts file but had no luck.

[Here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/coltoggle) is the example I am using from PrimeNG(Can test and see code there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of columns in the example is determined by **selectedColumns** array.
By default in the MultiSelect component, it will append any change to the end of the array.
So you should sort it after each change event on the MultiSelect. Add an event handler  **modelChange()**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cols" [ngModel]="selectedColumns" 
            (ngModelChange)='modelChange($event)'
                optionLabel="header"
                        selectedItemsLabel="{0} columns selected" [style]="{minWidth: '200px'}" defaultLabel="Choose Columns"></p-multiSelect>
```

And in your component ts file,

```
  modelChange(event) {
    console.log('change fired')
    this.selectedColumns = event;
    this.selectedColumns.sort(
      function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.field < b.field)
          return -1;
        if (a.field > b.field)
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }

    );
    console.log(this.selectedColumns);
  }
}
```

see a demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-template-fork-first-ow8wtw